# Displaying an array in a table view before the user see it

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on pulling in data from firebase and displaying it in a table view. I populate an array with the data received and use the array to fill the tableview, however the data is not being displayed.

I realized the issue is that the tableview is loading before the array gets populated. I've attempted putting a reloadData in viewdidload but this makes the data pop in after it is displayed and does not look clean.

How can I get the tableview to load the data before the view appears so that the transition is smooth?

This code is inside my viewdidload method :

```
let categoryRef = Database.database().reference().child("category/\(category)")
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        let uid = user.uid
        categoryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren(){
                for child in (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)! {
                    if let object = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let name = object["name"] as! String
                        self.nameArray.append(name)
                        self.categoryDict["\(name)"] = child.key as! String
                    }

                }
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reloading the data just after you appended all the children:

```
let categoryRef = Database.database().reference().child("category/\(category)")
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        let uid = user.uid
        categoryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChildren(){
                for child in (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)! {
                    if let object = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let name = object["name"] as! String
                        self.nameArray.append(name)
                        self.categoryDict["\(name)"] = child.key as! String
                    }

                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If that worked, please upvote and mark it as the correct answer so other people with your issue can see the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Call `func insertSections(IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` instead but remember to wrap it inside a call to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.  Also make sure your updating your UI on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

because

```
categoryRef.observeSingleEvent
```

is asynchronous, you should reload the table view after the block finishes, the way @barbarity proposes.

If you want a smoother transition, start this call

```
let categoryRef = Database.database().reference().child("category/\(category)")
```

before presenting your viewController, set the array and then present it.

But the practice in most of the cases with asynchronous processing is, start loading the data on viewDidLoad and have a UI loading mechanism (spinner)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So when does a table view get loaded? it is during the viewdidload method or whenever you set the delegate of the tableview?

Comment: If everything is set on viewDidLoad, it gets called. Otherwise you need to reloadData

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make other views which will make you sense the feeling of 'data pop' showed after the data is ready.

On the extreme condition, you may try to hide the whole tableview or even show Activity Indicator on the screen, then show the tableview and hide indicator after the datas for tableview is ready (In Objective-C):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //do init work ...

    self.tableview.hidden = YES;
    [self showIndicator];
    [self requestDataFinish:^{
          self.tableview.hidden = NO;
          [self hideIndicator];
          [self.tableview reload];
    }];        

}
```